# In an INSERT, how to make the null values to be zero or null?

Tags: sql, oracle, null, sql-insert

I have a table of 10 columns, and my `INSERT` statement only refers to specific columns in the table.

`INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE
     (COL_1, COL_2)
     VALUES
     (VAL_1, VAL_2);`

... or...

`INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE
     (COL_1, COL_2)
     SELECT VAL_1, VAL_2 FROM SCHEMA_2.TABLE_2;`

However, when I execute it, the other columns are inserted always with a null value, instead of having the corresponding one depending on the column type (i.e. number). This is, if I have a numeric column, I should see a zero.

How can I do that insert properly?

*** Please consider I have no DDL privileges & I'm trying to insert into an existing table.

Comment: Use a `DEFAULT` clause in the column definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question: that needs to be defined at table creation, determining default values. In this case, I wasn't able to do that because the table definition indicated NULL, even in the case of numbers.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach would probably to give your columns default values:

```
ALTER TABLE schema.table MODIFY (COL_1 NUMBER DEFAULT 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't have DDL privileges. Isn't there a way to use DML only?

Answer (score 1):

USE `DEFAULT` AS `0` for that column

or

```
        use NVL( column_name, 0 ) --as per oracle syntax 
        --this would mean whenever theres null found for 
          -- that column set it to 0 (will work on insert)
```

or

```
    Update column set column=0 where column IS NULL
    --(will work after insert as the name suggests update)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't have DDL privileges. Isn't there a way to use DML only?

Comment: Thanks, but that means I still need to enlist the columns I need to have updated with "0" instead of <null>. In that case, I think just adding all the columns in the INSERT clause from the beginning, including the "0" values will be the most time-saving option.

Comment: did you try with nvl

Comment: With nvl I would still need to refer to the columns I want to update.

Answer (score 1):

`DEFAULT` value it is; however, note that you have to pay attention to what you do because column might not get its default value. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id       number primary key,
  3     name     varchar2(10),
  4     address  varchar2(20) default 'Unknown',      --> columns with default 
  5     num_val  number       default 0               --> values
  6    );

Table created.
```

If you're inserting values **without** specifying column(s) that are supposed to get default values, everything will be as you'd want it to be:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Little');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME       ADDRESS                 NUM_VAL
---------- ---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 Little     Unknown                       0
```

See? Both `ADDRESS` and `NUM_VAL` got default values.

However, if you mention those columns in `INSERT` statement, although setting them to `NULL`, they won't be set to their default values but `NULL`:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, name, address, num_val)
  2    values (2, 'Foot', null, null);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME       ADDRESS                 NUM_VAL
---------- ---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 Little     Unknown                       0
         2 Foot
```

As you can see, row with `ID = 2` didn't get default values in `ADDRESS` and `NUM_VAL` columns.

Therefore, pay attention to what you do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't have DDL privileges. Isn't there a way to use DML only?

Comment: You're welcome. What DDL are you talking about? INSERT is DML ... Table I created is used just for testing purposes; you don't have to create any objects, just pay attention to column list in INSERT statement. [**EDIT**]Ah! ALTER it is, I presume. Another option is a database trigger, but that's also DDL. I wouldn't know whether there's any other option, apart from specifying desired values directly.

Comment: Yeah, but I think the table I'm trying to update don't have those "defaults" setup properly.

Answer (score 1):

Although frankly I don't *recommend* doing this, you *can* use a trigger to accomplish your goal:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SCHEMA.TABLE_BI
  BEFORE INSERT ON SCHEMA.TABLE
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.COL_1 := COALESCE(:NEW.COL_1, 0);        -- NUMBER column
  :NEW.COL_2 := COALESCE(:NEW.COL_2, ' ');      -- VARCHAR column
  :NEW.COL_3 := COALESCE(:NEW.COL_3, SYSDATE);  -- DATE column
END SCHEMA.TABLE_BI;
```

However, creating a trigger may require privileges you don't have.